# Does nginx cache (copy) my images?

Tags: nginx, http, cache

I'm using http public cache all over an images website to allow clients and anyone between the clients and my server (eg: cloudflare, isp, etc) to cache HTML, assets (js/css/icons), and images (the main content of the website). But I don't want nginx to cache these images, because it will take too much space. I'm not sure whether it's happening, I don't know how to check.

So how do I check, and if it's happening, how do I stop it, without also stopping client and proxies cache?

Note: I'm using nginx as web server with fastcgi, and not as a proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't explicitly set up nginx as a caching proxy, then it will not cache your images or other static content, but merely serve it from the filesystem.

Comment: I'm using fastcgi_cache, I forgot.

Comment: Oh but I'm using it in a .php location, so I guess it won't affect static images.